# Uniform contiunuity of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, uniform-continuity

If $g $ is uniformly continuous and $g(x) = (f(x))^2$,$f(x) \geq 0$, then is $f$ uniformly continuous?

So, $\forall \epsilon > 0 , $ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ with $|x - y|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f^2(x) - f^2(y)|<\epsilon$.

$|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{|f(x)+f(y)|}$

But how to proceed after this? , or is there any counterexample to this?

Comment: Hint: how many solutions are there to the equation $x^2 = b$ if $b > 0$ ?

Comment: there are two solutions,$x = +\sqrt{b} , -\sqrt{b}$

Comment: I think you need to add that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yes,just added that condition!

Comment: Hence, $f = \sqrt g$.

Comment: Hint: $g(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Kelenner: That's nice; you should post an answer!

Comment: @user21820 Done, thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composition of two uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous and $h(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous, hence so is $f(x) = h(g(x))$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality $|\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}|\leq \sqrt{|u-v|}$ valid for $u,v\geq 0$, for $u=f(x)^2=g(x)$ and $v=f(y)^2=g(y)$.

This give that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \sqrt{|g(x)-g(y)|}$$
and it is easy to finish.

Comment: It's worth noticing that you're basically showing uniform continuity of $\sqrt{x}$.